# spring rabbitmq: can't set id as a property?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I have a property file which contains queue whose value is queue_name

If I use the property in other please, then it works, but if I used it on "id", then it failed

```
<rabbit:queue id="${queue}" name="queue" />
```

The error is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.BindingFactoryBean#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'queue_name' while setting bean property 'destinationQueue'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ConnectorInputQueue_silo' is defined.
```

update:
I found the following log: it said bean ${queue} is created, so why didn't it replace ${queue} with the value of property of "queue"?

```
2014-11-21 05:27:11 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:220 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean '${queue}'
2014-11-21 05:27:11 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean '${queue}'
2014-11-21 05:27:11 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:524 - Eagerly caching bean '${queue}' to allow for resolving potential circular references
2014-11-21 05:27:11 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:478 - Finished creating instance of bean '${queue}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Show, please, more info to reproduce the issue. And pay attention that your StackTrace says:

> No bean named 'ConnectorInputQueue_silo' is defined.

Maybe it will help you somehow...