# why can not set id of a bean as property in spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have the following configuration in xml

```
  <bean id="${queue}" class="..." />
```

And then in the log I can see the following. Why doesn't spring replace queue with a property value?

```
2014-11-22 07:07:09 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:220 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean '${queue}'
2014-11-22 07:07:09 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:450 - Creating instance of bean '${queue}'
```

I have thought it's related to rabbitmq only, but looks like for anybean, it won't apply property for ID.

[spring rabbitmq: can't set id as a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041072/spring-rabbitmq-cant-set-id-as-a-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'id' is XML-related attribute and should be unique plain string across the XML file. For your purposes you can use 'name' attribute. See [5.3.1 Naming beans](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-beanname) section in Spring documentation.

```
 <bean id="queueId" name="${queue}" class="..." />
```

However I would not recommend such manipulation as it is unusual and decreases maintainability of your code.